# How to style react-tabulator table?

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

Can anyone please provide me some info on how to style a react-tabulator table? I have been trying to change header color, borders etc. but in vain. I only found class names in the documentation like `className="table-bordered table-striped"` but that wont help me. I want to create custom styling. Please help me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clone the existing style css file and modify it, example:
https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/master/demo/src/index.js#L7

Then import it to your project.
I plan to add some Doc for styling soon. Thanks.